# iOS 6.1 Safari isn't setting Accept-Encoding

Tags: ios, http, safari, nginx, http-headers

My test case is just an HTML script tag being added to the head, but basically every HTTP request on iOS Safari isn't setting the Accept-Encoding header.

I tracked the HTTP request with [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/) and verified that the request is indeed going out to our Nginx server with the below headers.

HTTP Request:

```
GET http://www.website.com/8EF47773B9E25308C1F124FF701E607A.cache.js HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.com
Referer: http://www.website.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B141
```

HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 22:56:39 GMT
Expires: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 22:56:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Feb 2013 17:54:27 GMT
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Content-Length: 1042909
Connection: keep-alive
```

Merely adding "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" with the exact same request headers above (using Curl) will come back with a gzipped response.

This also only happens on the device; using an iOS simulator will add the proper Accept-Encoding headers.

Is this intended behavior of iOS Safari? I've scoured the internet for more information on this with little results.

Comment: The proxy is likely to be interfering with things. Can you retest without that?

Comment: Yep, naturally 30 minutes later I figure out that Paros proxy tosses out all Accept-Encoding headers. Verified it with CharlesProxy to be sure, everything is working fine. What a waste of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paros proxy tosses out all Accept-Encoding headers.